# Let sonarRunner use the spring boot resolution strategy for dependency versions?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, sonar-runner

I'd like to use the SonarQube-gradle-plugin to analyze my multi-module project. My project is based on spring-boot, which sets a default version for spring boot dependencies, e.g. I can define my dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
}
```

and the spring boot gradle plugin will insert the fitting versions for the gradle build.

After applying the sonarRunner plugin and running `gradle sonarRunner`, I get the following error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':admin-db:runtime'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/C:/A/m2repos/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa//spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-.pom
      file:/C:/A/m2repos/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa//spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-.jar
      ...
```

It seems the sonarRunner-plugin does not get the versions the spring boot plugin has set.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What versions of Spring Boot and Gradle are you using?

Comment: gradle 1.7, spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE

Comment: It works for me. Have you definitely applied the Spring Boot plugin to the module where you're declaring dependencies without any versions? Perhaps you can share a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem

Comment: No, the Spring Boot plugin is not applied for the submodule, because it is just a library and not a application. I thought, declaring the dependency to the spring-boot-gradle-plugin in the buildscript section will activate the dependency management of spring boot. Anyway, a `gradle bN` runs successful, but `gradle sonarRunner` does not.

Comment: I assembled a minimal file set to reproduce the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvrw0c99nsz0ppo/sonarRunnerTest.zip?dl=0